# Why Sonar shows "to be compliant to J2EE, a webapp should not use any thread" for my desktop application?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I try to analyze my code with Sonar, but it shows the following message:

```
To be compliant to J2EE, a webapp should not use any thread.
```

The question is why sonar shows me the error, although my app is a desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PMD rule specific to J2EE webapp, you should update your quality profile to not apply this rule (and the related ones) to your desktop application.